# Deezer grad Date

Tags: python, deezer

how can I set the modification date of a playlist as a variable?

Playlist : https://www.deezer.com/de/playlist/1313617925

at the top of the playlist is:
Updated: 11 hours ago

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljjdE.jpg)

My Script:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

access_token = 'xxxxxx'
playlist_id = '1313617925'
url = f'https://api.deezer.com/playlist/{playlist_id}'
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
total_duration = response['duration']
print(total_duration)
```

Comment: The f-string isn't format probably. the correct way headers = {f'Authorization: Bearer {access_token}'}